# string split and setting based on count in java

Tags: java, string

I have a source code like

```
String delay = "10:20:30";
int Retrycount=3;
long DelayTime=0;
```

I have to split and set this in `DelayTime` based on count value which is int.

For example, if Retrycount is 1 the value should be 10.
The delay value may increase like "10:20:30:40:50"

How to set the value based on count?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: can you elaborate more, does `Retrycount` indicates which part of `delay` to be assigned in `DelayTime`?

Answer (score 0):

What you want seems to be two things:

1. Split a string up by colons.
2. Pick the nth of the substrings.

The simplest implementation is something like this:

`public String splitAndPick(String splitMe, int pickMe) {
    String[] splitString = splitMe.split(":");
    return splitString[pickMe - 1];
}`

You can then set delaytime like so:

`long delayTime = splitAndPick(delay, retryCount);`

Also, I'm assuming that you're doing homework:
In Java, you start variables with lowercase.
If you have several words, you make the first letter of every word that is not the first capital.
For example:
delay, not Delay.
retryCount, not Retrycount.
delayTime, not DelayTime.

This convention makes it easier for other programmers to see what you mean when you do things.

See [Sun's old styleguide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) and [Google's style guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html) for examples. I recommend sticking with google's, to be honest, Sun's old guide is mostly for historical context, although they differ very little for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution.

```
String delay = "10:20:30";
int Retrycount=3;
long DelayTime=0;
//split function with 2 argument will not split the string further, as in our case we need to split the string till Retrycount
String[] values = delay.split( ":", Retrycount+1 );
//fetch the element based on index , index starts from 0 , so we need to subtract one from  "Retrycount"
System.out.print( values[Retrycount-1] );
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, you always should provide some explanation for why it does so.

Comment: it's pretty simple , however i am adding some explanation .